# How to init a vector using a specific range of elements stored in a list?

Tags: c++, list, vector, initialization

I got a `list` and a `vector`:

```
list<int> l;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    l.push_back(i);

vector<int> v;
```

I want to initialize `v` using the first 5 elements in `l`, that is in this case `{0,1,2,3,4}`.

Besides `for` loop coupled with `v.push_back`, any other way? `memcpy` or `copy`?

PS: I am not using C++0x/C++11 at present.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, er, anything wrong with my question?

Comment: In C++11 there's `std::copy_n` (once you consider upgrading your compiler)

Comment: @hmjd, sorry, I am not using `boost` either.

Comment: @jrok, yes, I am considering upgrade the compiler, but how? Install the newest g++?

Comment: Why not? I'm using gcc 4.6.1 and `copy_n` is already implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [can](http://codepad.org/0Bo0WwUF) use `std::copy` and `std::advance` (instead of `+`, for the non-random-access iterator):

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   std::list<int> l;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       l.push_back(i);

   std::vector<int> v;
   v.reserve(5);

   std::list<int>::iterator start = l.begin(), end = start;
   std::advance(end, 5);
   std::copy(start, end, std::back_inserter(v));

   std::cout << v.size();   // 5
}
```

The `advance` is "slow", though, because of the nature of `std::list<>`; that's why `op+` is not available for the `std::list<>::iterator`.

Comment: Using `std::copy`? Plz elaborate on that.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of a for loop? You essentially traversing your collection twice, advancing your iterator first in std::advance and then in std::copy. It's fine for 5, but when you would have ten million elements in your list, this would be a real waste of time. So formally the answer is correct, but why would you want to do that? for loop with vector::resize would work faster.

Comment: @mezhaka: Indeed, you wouldn't want to do it. I did say it's slow, and a previous revision of my answer mentioned that it leads to double-traversal. A loop would be better; and you should use `vector::reserve` actually.

Comment: @naltmann: Yep, true. I didn't want to get bogged down by that, originally, but I suppose we might as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was addressed to the Alcott rather than you. Thanks for the correction (reserve).

Comment: @mezhaka: Why would it be addressed to Alcott? You were talking about _my_ answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid looping, this is the very nature of a list.  There's certainly no guarantee as to how the data is stored so you can't use something like memcpy.  If you don't want to access the elements of a container by looping through them, you shouldn't be using a list.

As other answers have pointed out there are a number of compact ways you can use iterators to do this, but all of them will ultimately loop through your list.

Comment: He's looking for a solution that loops _for_ him.

Comment: That's not what the question says.

Comment: Well, yes, it basically is. He even wonders _out loud_ whether `std::copy` can help. `std::copy` is a wrapper around a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct convF
{
    convF( std::list<int>::const_iterator it_):it(it_){}

    int operator()()
    {
        return *it++;
    }

    std::list<int>::const_iterator it;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l;
    std::vector<int> v;

    l.push_back(5);
    l.push_back(4);
    l.push_back(3);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(9);
    l.push_back(11);
    l.push_back(13);
    l.push_back(15);
    l.push_back(16);

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ), 5, convF(l.begin()) );

    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int> (std::cout, " "));
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the most simple solution is:

```
list<int> l;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    l.push_back(i);

vector<int> v(l.begin(), l.begin()+5);
```

This constructor takes two iterators marking the beginning and one element after the end.

Comment: No, you can't do arithmetic operation on `list::iterator`.